# NPM: skip dev dependencies when installing a package from Github

Tags: github, npm, dependencies

Is it possible to exclude dev dependencies when installing directly from [GitHub](https://github.com/)?

Unfortunately the command

```sh
npm install --only=production my-repo@github:path-to/my-repo
```

doesn't seem to work, it only excludes dev dependencies specified in the current `package.json` file, not the ones specified in the package I am installing.